# 1С отправка POST запроса с телом base64строка

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Всем Привет.

Возникла проблема с передачей изображения на веб сервер из программы 1С 8.2.
Текстовые данные отлично передаются кроме изображения.
Делаю так :

```
ЗаголовокHTTP = Новый Соответствие();
ЗаголовокHTTP.Вставить("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
СерверПриемник = "port.rrham.com";
НТТР = Новый HTTPСоединение(СерверПриемник);

Файл = ("C:\img22.jpg");
ДД = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
Строка64 = Base64Строка(ДД);

СтрокаPOSTЗапроса = "";
СтрокаPOSTЗапроса = СтрокаPOSTЗапроса + "&image=" + Строка64;

АдресСтраницы = "/data/api.php?call=add";
Попытка
ЗапросHTTP = Новый HTTPСоединение(АдресСтраницы, ЗаголовокHTTP);
ЗапросHTTP.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки(СтрокаPOSTЗапроса);
ОтветHTTP = НТТР.ОтправитьДляОбработки(ЗапросHTTP);
Исключение
Сообщить(ОписаниеОшибки());
Возврат;
КонецПопытки;
```

А на сервере всё как обычно

```
 function add($image){
 ....
 $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $path = '../data/'.$upload_image.'.jpg';
 ....
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));}
```

Но в итоге я получаю ломанное изображение. Я пробовал сохранить сохранить  `$upload_image.'.jpg';` в `txt` текстовом формате и заметил что в кодировке отсутствуют некоторые спец символы к примеру `+` , перед отправкой символ плюс был а на сервере они отсутствуют вместо них просто пробелы.

Отрывок для примера
Символ плюс есть
`RgZ+msnCHzc126J8Q3Rt791bbe8HPBrLcGr9Njoa4jbUaX2ns8ecOdDiV4/hevTj`
Символ плюс отсутствует
`RgZ msnCHzc126J8Q3Rt791bbe8HPBrLcGr9Njoa4jbUaX2ns8ecOdDiV4/hevTj`

Подскажите , что я делаю не так?

Comment: Content-Type при передаче изображения разве не [image/jpeg](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96_(Discrete)_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8) должен быть?

Comment: @Jack_oS - Да но у меня помимо изображения передаются и другие текстовые данные , просто я их не указал здесь. Такие данные как наименование и код.

Comment: пишут, что Base64Строка может дописывать перевод строки и возврат каретки: https://pro1c.org.ua/index.php?showtopic=22966# не ваш случай?

Comment: @Jack_oS - Я думаю проблема возможно в другом , так как записал  полученную Base64Строка в текстовой документ затем онлайн сервисом закодировал это же изображение в  Base64 и сравнил . Они идентичны . И попробовал считать в переменную из текстового документа куда сохранил Base64Строка  с последующей отправкой переменной на веб сервер , результат тот же. При получении на сервере куда то теряются все символы `+` плюса в кодировке.

Comment: @Jack_oS - Когда делаю всё на java то всё работает.  К примеру :  `private String 
        convertToString() {ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
        ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,60,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT); }`

Comment: @Jack_oS - Возможно дело в получении массива байтов. Так как для меня 1С это в новинку я ещё не особо разобрался как она устроена.

Comment: или php чудит: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819386/14785750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй отправлять данные через multipart/form-data, у меня так работает, пример:

```
Процедура кОтправитьДанные(Команда)
    АдресСтраницы = "/data/api.php?call=add";
    Хост = "port.rrham.com";
    
    Файл = ("C:\img22.jpg");
    ДД = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
    Строка64 = Base64Строка(ДД);
    
    // подготовим файл с данными для отправки
    имяФайлаОтправки = ПолучитьимяВременногоФайла("txt");
    boundary = СтрЗаменить(Строка(Новый УникальныйИдентификатор()), "-", "");
     
    ЗаписьТекста = Новый ЗаписьТекста(имяФайлаОтправки, КодировкаТекста.ANSI, Символы.ПС, Ложь);
     
    // ++ поле формы html
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""image""" + Символы.ПС);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("");
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку(Строка64);
    // -- поле формы html
    
    
    // закроем разделитель
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary + "--");
    ЗаписьТекста.Закрыть();
    
    // определим размер файла
    ФайлОтправки = Новый Файл(имяФайлаОтправки);
    РазмерФайлаОтправки = XMLСтрока(ФайлОтправки.Размер());
    
    // передадим данные на сервер 
    Заголовки = Новый Соответствие();
    Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary);
    Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Lenght", РазмерФайлаОтправки);
    
    имяВыходногоФайла = ПолучитьИмяВременногоФайла("txt");
    
    ЗапросHTTP = Новый HTTPЗапрос(АдресСтраницы, Заголовки);
    ЗапросHTTP.УстановитьИмяФайлаТела(имяФайлаОтправки);
    
    Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение(Хост);
    Ответ = Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(ЗапросHTTP);
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Огромное Спасибо Вам Yura ! Это Действительно работает.  Попробую расширить ваш запрос для передачи остального текстового контента на сервер.  Ваш метод Спас моё время.

Comment: не за что, рад что смог помочь

Comment: а могу ли я поменять кодировку на utf8 для передачи текста на кириллице ? Или добавить в ЗапросHTTP и другие строковые данные ?

Comment: если здесь 
ЗаписьТекста = Новый ЗаписьТекста(имяФайлаОтправки, КодировкаТекста.ANSI, Символы.ПС, Ложь);
поменять кодировку, то на сервере массив POST пустой. Другие строковые данные добавляются также как в блоке с коментами // ++ поле формы html

Comment: Если в блоке передать текстовые данные на кириллице  то в базу на сервере пишутся только символы вопроса вместо букв. Может средствами php попробовать перекодировать?

Comment: Или попробовать выполнить ОбъединитьФайлы

Comment: Решить проблему с кодировкой кириллицы удалось создав два файла с параметрами и далее   ОбъединитьФайлы(массивФайлов, имяФайлаОтправки);

Comment: хорошо что удалось решить проблему с кодировкой, теперь тоже буду знать

Answer (score 0):

в 1с закодируй переменную Строка64 с помощью метода глобального контекста "КодироватьСтроку" и дальше делай как ты написал выше, например:

```
ДД = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
Строка64 = Base64Строка(ДД);

**Строка64 = КодироватьСтроку(Строка64, СпособКодированияСтроки.КодировкаURL);**
```

*Если данное решение помогло, то не забудь его отметить галочкой, спасибо*

Comment: СпособКодированияСтроки как я понял появился только в версии 8.3 , версия на с которой я работаю 8.2.  У меня в основном проблема в том что не могу получить один из символов в строке , символ плюс `+`. Символ плюс абсолютно не передаётся.

Comment: Пробовал даже передать просто строку `Стр1 = "abg!@#123+=+abg!@#123";` на сервер приходит эта же строка вот так `abg!@#123 = abg!@#123`.

Comment: Да, это знаю, он почему-то режет символы. СпособКодирования появился в 8.3

Comment: Режет только один из символов, символ плюс `+` с остальными символами всё вроде нормально... Думаю это проблема самой среды разработки, 8.2 в топку.

Comment: 8.3 тоже самое - проверял, только если использовать метод КодироватьСтроку, тогда ок

Comment: Ясно, значит причина в версии...